# Trace map fails to be $G$ homomorphism

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and $M,N$ be two $G$ modules then $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,N)$ is a  $G$ module with action $$G\times \rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,N)\rightarrow \rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,N)$$ mapping
 $(\sigma,\eta)\mapsto \eta^{\sigma}$ where $\eta^{\sigma}(m)=\sigma\eta(\sigma^{-1}m)$.

Define Trace map to be the map $T:\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,N)\rightarrow \rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,N)$ where
 $$\eta\mapsto\sum_{\sigma\in G }\eta^{\sigma}$$

As $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,N)$ is a $G$ module and trace map is used left and right when defining cup products, we expect $T$ to be a $G$ module homomorphism as well. But unfortunately it turns out to be not.

For $\tau\in G$ we have 
$$\begin{align}T(\eta^{\tau})(m)
&=\sum_{\sigma\in G}((\eta^{\tau})^{\sigma})(m)
=\sum_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(\eta^{\tau})(\sigma^{-1}m)
=\sum_{\sigma\in G}\sigma\tau \eta (\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}m)\\
\tau T(\eta)(m)&=\tau \sum_{\sigma\in G}\eta^{\sigma}(m)=\tau \sum_{\sigma\in G}\sigma\eta(\sigma^{-1}m)
=\sum_{\sigma\in G}\tau\sigma \eta (\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}m)
\end{align}$$

So, $T(\eta^{\tau})\neq \tau T(\eta)$. Is my calculation wrong or my guess is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sums are the same and are equal to
$$
\sum_{\theta\in G}\theta\eta(\theta^{-1}m).
$$

Comment: I could not realise that as my $\tau$ is fixed element, varying $\sigma$ over all elements , the collection $\{\sigma\tau:\sigma\in G\}$ is same as $\{\tau\sigma:\sgam\}$ .. So, sum is same... Got it...